# Having multiple critical sections for synchronization of two Shared Queues

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, winapi, synchronization

I have two 40 threads writing to a Shared Queue A and a single thread reading from the shared Queue A.

I have synchronized the threads using

> EnterCriticalSection(&cs);
>
> //Do something
>
> LeaveCriticalSection(&cs);

Now there is another Shared Queue B and 40 threads will be writing to the Shared Queue B and another separated thread will be reading from this Shared Queue B.
Now for sharing this Shared Queue B and synchronizing it among the threads, do I need to have a separate Critical Section lets say csB? or only a single Critical Section cs can serve the purpose?

Answer (score 1):

You don't *have* to use a separate critical section, but using separate critical sections will allow for more parallelism. If the reads and writes from and to the different queues are highly synchronized you may be able to put all actions on queue B in the same critical sections used for queue A, in which case the critical section can be reused. Beware however that such reuse may also lead to possible deadlock situations.

Note that a 'critical section' is really a range of code in a thread. What different critical sections can share is the guard (typically a semaphore) to these code ranges. So all code ranges manipulating some queue are guarded by the same guard to make sure that updates on the queue are not interfering with each other, as that could result in corruption of the queue.

Comment: Thanka a lot but don't you think that using same critical section will add delay e.g. if Shared Queue A is free to be written but Shared Queue B is using the cs than cs will not be given to Shared Queue A and it will have to wait until shared queue B leaves the cs even though shared QueueA has nothing to do with Shared Queue B still it will wait for it to free up the cs.

Comment: @AyeshaHassan That is exactly the reason that parallelism may be reduced by reusing the guard for different queues. So my advice would be to use different guards for different queues. The guards are only there to protect the integrity of the queues.